# How do I get a custom help text on a link field if title of the field is hidden?

Tags: entities, 8, navigation

I created a link field, and disabled its title, put some custom help text for the link field. It only shows the default help text underneath, like below but with no custom help text.

> Start typing the title of a piece of content to select it. You can also enter an internal path such as /node/add or an external URL such as http://example.com. Enter `<front>` to link to the front page.

How can I only get a custom help text rather than the default help text? Eventually, is there a way to get both?

Comment: Seriously, you could have take the effort not to copy&paste the title question again (uppercase starting letter...) and then continuing with a question which absolutely doesn't make sense at all. 

If you want to get proper answers, you have to sacrifice your time into the question's wording.  Even if you have language problems.

Comment: @ssibal Anyway I fix my problem. Next time I will make sure to explain properly thanks.